# Facebook Share Button for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

In my application i am using Facebook SDK,

I have a mark as favourite button on my view

```
  UIImage *favNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Fav_normal"];
UIImage *favPressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Fav_pressed"];
[favButton setImage:favNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[favButton setImage:favPressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
favButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, favNormal.size.width, favNormal.size.height);
//    favButton.center = CGPointMake(190, 70);
favButton.center = CGPointMake(85+(favNormal.size.width/2), 73);
[headView addSubview:favButton];

favButton.enabled = NO;
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ProjectServerRequests ASIFormDataRequestForSrcipt:@"isFavorite"];
[request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", Id] forKey:@"sid"];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"isFavorite response: %@", response);
    if([response isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {
        [favButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Fav_normal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [fav setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Fav_pressed"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    favoriteButton.enabled = YES;
}];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Now i am trying to make a share button so that it should share the specific URL on Fb that is on the view, lik the view has 
**www.my-website.com/key-chain** this URL 
I am storing the Url in **NSMutableString * url_selected**

so by clicking the share button i want that it should take that particular Url and share that URL on Fb,

can any one please tell me how to coding for the Fb share button inside my application... ?

Comment: Do you need to support previous versions of iOS? Now you have native support for FB sharing on iOS 6. It doesn't get easier than that.

Comment: yes i need support for previous versions also .. can't it be done using this .. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using iOS6, try the Social Framework included in the iOS SDK with a tutorial available here - http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com/integrating-facebook-ios-6/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [share kit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) for FB sharing like url,text. install latest share kit & implement it.

Its easy be implemented.

Comment: so share kit is used with FBSDK or separately or can't it be done using the FBSDK alone ?? .. sorry to ask but i am kind of new to this

Comment: share kit is actually share text,url,image on social sites like facebook,twitter,Email,tumbler etc...yes you can also use FBSDK alone...

Comment: @user1877823 If I were you and **only** needed Facebook sharing I wouldn't use ShareKit, it's too big to implement just one sharing option.

Comment: so how should i use FBSDK alone for sharing .. any code for that ??